# SQL Server match partial text in the comma separated varchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I have a `VARCHAR` column `category_text` in the table that contain tags to a notification stored. I have three tags Query, Complaint and Suggestion and column can have one or more values separated by comma. I am applying a filter and filter can have one or more values as well in comma separated pattern.

Now what I want is to retrieve all the rows that contain at least one tag based on the filter user is applying, for instance user can select 'query,suggestion' as a filter and result would be all the rows that contain one of the tags i.e. query or suggestion.

```
select 
    t.category_text  
from 
    real_time_notifications t
where 
    charindex('query, suggestion, complaints', t.category_text) > 0
order by 
    t.id desc
```

Comment: Fix your data model!  Do not store multiple values in a string.  Then you can handle your queries more sensibly.

Comment: And if you fix your model, then this problem is trivial. The fact that are you *are* using denormalised data is why you're struggling with what should be a simple problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new table, like user_category (user.id link to user table, category) and create an index on both. It will speed up a lot for searching and ease your future maintenance a lot.

If you still persist to do that, create an inline function to split string to records and then merge to test.